# External provisioner "alicloud/disk fails to create volume

Tags: kubernetes, storage, alibaba-cloud

I use managed k8s silution on AliCloud.
I created storageClass such as:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: alicloud-pv-class
parameters:
  type: cloud_ssd
  regionid: cn-beijing
  zoneid: cn-beijing-g
provisioner: alicloud/disk
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

When I try to create pvc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: node-pv
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: alicloud-pv-class
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi
```

I get:

```
Name:          node-pv
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  alicloud-pv-class
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: alicloud/disk
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  11s (x6 over 75s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "alicloud/disk" or manually created by system administrator
```

Eventhough I create manually pvc and  bind it to pv and install helm  chart  for zookeeeper I  am getting from the  pod:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/zookeeper/data': Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how exactly that pod is created? How exactly that storage is provisioned?

Comment: I use helm chart from bitnami/zookeper - https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/zookeeper

Comment: The strange thing is - if I remove the dynamically created pvc and manualy create the same name pvc binded properly to pv - it will fail with mentioned "Permission denied". If I create test pod manifest with pvc manually created before pod creation - it will work without problem.

Comment: Any dynamic pvc - will fail with Warining: PersistentVolumeClaim data-pvc is Pending, not bounded.

Comment: do you have all the needed plugins installed? https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/86785.htm

Comment: @Nick  -  yes. Regarding the documentation you need to install plugins only  if k8s  was installed before  06 Feb 2018. I use Managed Serveless K8s cluster.  And its  new  installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the issue but the problems I had was related to Aliyun Managed Serverless K8s. Even Aliyun Support admitted that such configuration is difficult. They have not provided any solution. We decided to go with Managed K8s (non-serveless). We use [Terraform scripts](https://github.com/terraform-alicloud-modules/terraform-alicloud-managed-kubernetes). Everything works
out of  the  box including Ingress, LogTrail, PvC which were a real pain with  serverless managed k8s.

The  point is - dont  waste your time with Managed Serveless K8s if you need logs and pvc. It doesnt work - at least hasn't worked for us and not much help from Aliyun support for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alicloud ASK, this file https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/serverless-k8s-examples/blob/master/volumes/alicloud-disk-controller.yaml is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the automatic provisioning to work ("waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "alicloud/disk" or manually created by system administrator"), you may need to install the `csi-provisioner` add-on and/or use provisioner `diskplugin.csi.alibabacloud.com`. Documentation is at https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/ack/serverless-kubernetes/user-guide/storage-csi/#title-4sj-fr4-u1a